# Build Error Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

```
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
<ij_msg_gr>Gradle import errors<ij_msg_gr><ij_nav>D:\Important_Docs\Projects\Backup\RLPHYC\android-utils\build.gradle<ij_nav><i><b>project ':android-utils': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration</b><eol>Details: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':android-utils:generateLintModuleInfo'.<eol>Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion.</i>
<ij_msg_gr>Gradle import errors<ij_msg_gr><ij_nav>D:\Important_Docs\Projects\Backup\RLPHYC\app\build.gradle<ij_nav><i><b>project ':app': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration</b><eol>Details: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:generateLintModuleInfo'.<eol>Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion.</i>
Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion.
```

> Tried to invalidate cache restart also used ext in top-level Gradle and also deleted Gradle folder Still error continues

No problem with the Gradle version tried the same with different Gradle versions

Comment: This happens to me when changing the Android Gradle Plugin from 4.0.2 to 4.1.0

Comment: May be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171801043 or https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171171054. Please give those issues a ⭐️ star if you are experiencing them.

Answer (score 10):

like @Vacexe said, this is dexcount plugin's bug.

You can resovle this problem by update dexcount plugin version to 2.0.0:

```
classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

could not create task ':app:generateLintModuleInfo'

I had this above problem when i created a new project in android studio. I visited stackoverflow got this question.

then as i didn't got anything i tried to compare build.gradle(:app) files of previously successfully build projects I saw that, their was this extra line

```
 buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
```

you will get it bellow compileSdkVersion. just remove above line and sync the gradle file. for me everything worked smoothly later.

Comment: reducing it to `buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"` also works.

Comment: Removed the line and it worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in our project after uplift gradle plugin to 4.1.0 version and it has been solved by removing this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

- Firstly check what a plugin in use in your project
- Secondly try to recompile without it to find a tricky one

Comment: or just update you dexcount plugin version : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841672/669647

Answer (score 1):

They removed some deprecated methods from the DSL. So not-up-to-date plugins will crash miserably on this update.
In fact, issue can come from any gradle plugin that uses deprecated methods from the gradle Android DSL.
Just run

```
$ ./gradlew clean assemble --stacktrace
```

to understand what plugin calls a deprecated (removed) method, and in general this plugin has a more recent version that no longer uses the deprecated DSL method.
In my case, this was junit5, but one has to do the per-case verification.

Comment: And they released 4.1.1 a few minutes ago. It re-enables some removed versions, with deprecation warning. This is not a pretext to not update old dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

could not create task ':app:generateLintModuleInfo'

I had this above problem when i created a new project in android studio.
i tried to change gradle version from 4.2.1 to 3.4.3 in project gradle,then it build successfully.like this-

```
 dependencies {
  classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3"}
```

i think this problem is something wrong appears in gradle version and buildToolsVersion etc,when i creat a new project,it use the leatest android version in default,now is targetSdkVersion 32.

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me when I updated to Android Studio 4.1 and then I changed back to previous settings and everything is working now.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle (project)

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: In my case, I had to create a new project and copy all the source files to a new one and I think the problem was with the difference between the kotlin version and my android studio kotlin version

Comment: Obviously, not updating is not a sustainable solution. I'm still wondering why this AS version and AGP version fail / crash. The other comment about the project's Kotlin version being outdated, or the AS Kotlin plugin version being outdated, do not apply to my project: they're up to date, yet by build fails with the same errors.

Comment: just update you dexcount plugin version : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841672/669647